# Selforthogonal modules over Artinian Gorenstein rings

Tags: ac.commutative-algebra, homological-algebra

Let $R$ be a local artinian Gorenstein ring and $M$ a finitely generated $R$-module, then
$\mathrm{Ext}_R^1(M,M) = 0$ if only if $M$ is projective?

Comment: Dear TmobiusX, would you care to explain any motivation for your question?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This would be a very strong version of the Auslander-Reiten Conjecture ([see here](https://www.leuschke.org/research/AR-Conjecture/), for example) in the Gorenstein case.  The Conjecture is still open, though many partial results are known.

By the way, [this paper](https://doi.org/10.1016/j.jalgebra.2008.04.027) (ScienceDirect link, may not be visible to everyone) claims a proof of the Conjecture in the Gorenstein case, which would give an affirmative answer to your question, but I --- and several other people I've talked to --- believe there is a gap in the proof.  Their assumption is that $\mathrm{Ext}_R^{i}(M,M)=0$ for $i =1,2$.  The questionable step is at the top of page 2163, the second line, where they say "therefore ... is exact".

Edit 2023-05-15: The paper I referred to above is: "When are Torsionless modules projective?", by Rong Luo and Zhaoyong Huang,
Journal of Algebra 320 (2008) 2156-2164, MR2437647.

Comment: Fixed the leuschke.org link, thanks. Included citation information for the other paper, which I should have done at the time.

Comment: Is this result now accepted by the community, or is there still a belief that a gap may exist?

Comment: As far as I know the situation is still the same as in 2010. I still doubt the result. It has been cited in half-a-dozen papers since then.

Comment: I see. Thank you for your insight.